# Why does editMode in SwiftUI not work in toolbar?

Tags: swiftui, editmode

I'm learning the editMode in SwiftUI. I found that if I put the EditButton in a stack, the editMode will switch between .active and .inactive. If I put the EditButton in the toolbar, the editMode does not change if I tap the EditButton.

The following works.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(editMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? "Active" : "Inactive")
            EditButton()
        }
    }
}
```

The following does not work.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text(editMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? "Active" : "Inactive")
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The second question is why I cannot use the isEditing property as below?

```
Text((editMode?.isEditing ?? false) ? "Active" : "Inactive")

// The following works:
Text(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false ? "Active" : "Inactive")
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: 1) in toolbar works as well, Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. 2) edit mode environment variable is of `Binding<EditMode>?` type